# Box-shadow is being cut off of the image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

The image should look like this.

box-shadow added to the code:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEP1g.png)

Instead, it is looking like this and I don't know why and how to fix it. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RASb6.png)

You can see the box-shadow is being cut off of the image on all 4 sides.

How do I fix it so that the image isn't being cut off?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/8mgvn40u/

```css
.curtain {
  width: 550px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
   
}
.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}
.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}
.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.curtain:hover .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-500%);
}
.curtain:hover .j2 {
  transform: translateX(500%);
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">

  <div class="split-wrap">
    <div class="j1">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="j2">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of overflow, `bow-shadow` gets cut-off (already said) , You could  also use transform to easily keep the shadows within the visible area.

increase first the hidden overflow area then decrease what stands inside. smaller it won't get clipped anymore.

example of the idea with a short fixed involving : `transform:scale(1.1)`VS `transform:scale(0.9)` to keep a close ratio of the initial layout size.

```css
.curtain {
  width: 550px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.split-wrap{
transform:scale(1.1);
}
.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
  transform:scale(0.9);
   
}
.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}
.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}
.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.curtain:hover .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-500%);
}
.curtain:hover .j2 {
  transform: translateX(500%);
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">

  <div class="split-wrap">
    <div class="j1">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="j2">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I get the size to 180, how it was originally? Is that possible to do?

Comment: @coding4532 , just do the math :)  scale down 0.9  is about scale up 1.1111 needed to get back to 1

Comment: How do you do the math? What gave you 1.1111? So I know how to do it. What am I calculating?

Comment: @coding4532 scaling down 10% : 180 x 0.9 = 162  (10% = 18) .  the other way round is :  180 / 162= 1.111.. and  1.1111... x 162 = 180

Comment: yes, the same way :180 x 0.8 = ... then use these numbers you get

Answer (score 0):

that happening because you gave `overflow: hidden` to `.j1` and `.j2`, changing it into `overflow: visible` will fix the `box-shadow` issue but will mess up your curtain animation.

alternatively you can make `.j1` and `.j2` bigger but with padding so the `box-shadow` won't overlap it.